# How to sumarize "sickness time" to the end of order - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum

In that case i have "sickness" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------------+
| Id_SICK|ID_WORKER| FNAME   | LNAME   | BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE              | SICKNESS_TIME |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 6      |   17    | PAUL    | KING    |2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-20 15:00:00    |    16:00:00   | 
| 7      |   17    | PAUL    | KING    |2019-03-25 07:00:00  |2019-03-25 15:00:00    |    8:00:00    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
```

"Workers" table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 17       |  PAUL   |  KING   |
| 18       |  SAM    |  BULK   |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

"Orders" table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

"Order_status" table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | ORDER_DONE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 47       |   17    |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|  NO        |
| 48       |   17    |    20   |2019-03-20 06:44:12  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|  NO        |
| 50       |   17    |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|  YES       |
| 51       |   18    |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|  NO        |
| 52       |   18    |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|  NO        |
| 53       |   18    |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

What i've done:

I can to sumarize "total time" of each other workers (in order_status table) on the order including with sumarizing "sickness time" from Sickness table. I have selected workers (LNAME, FNAME) orders (DESC_ORDER and NUMBER_ORDER) and "TOTAL TIME" on order from each other workers correctly too. I wrote the mysql command in below:

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
   workers.lname, 
   order_statusAgg.number_order,
   workers.id_worker,
   order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
   SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'TOTAL TIME', 
   IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(sickAgg.vtime)),'00:00:00') AS 'LEAVE TIME'
FROM workers 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT leave.id_worker, SUM((datediff(sickness.end_date, sickness.begin_date) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(sickness.end_date)) - time_to_sec(time(sickness.begin_date)))) AS vtime 
FROM sickness
GROUP BY sickness.id_worker) sickAgg
           ON sickAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
   LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, 
SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                   Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
       INNER JOIN orders 
           ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker) order_statusAgg
           ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 
WHERE  order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker;
```

Then i get:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | TOTAL TIME | Sickness_time| 
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|  PAUL   |  KING   | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   24:00:00   |   
|  SAM    |  BULK   | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   00:00:00   |   
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Okey but on the other hand that order was finished in 23-03-2019. PAUL KING had a sickness in 25-03-2019 too and his sickness time shouldn't added during this order which he was doing. So in this case that should be:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | TOTAL TIME | Sickness_time| 
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|  PAUL   |  KING   | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   16:00:00   |   
|  SAM    |  BULK   | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   00:00:00   |   
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

I'm wondering if that is about that code issue?

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT leave.id_worker, SUM((datediff(sickness.end_date, sickness.begin_date) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(sickness.end_date)) - time_to_sec(time(sickness.begin_date)))) AS vtime 
FROM sickness
GROUP BY sickness.id_worker) sickAgg
           ON sickAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
```

Has someone ideas how to deal with summarizing it till the end of duration of the order? Is it that possible? I was searching any idea but I'm not mysql guru. Thank you for any help.

Comment: First of all, fix your `GROUP BY`.  Once the `GROUP BY` is fixed, we'll discuss about fixing your logic.

Comment: @Eric is right this is how you should use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in SQL

Comment: @Eric ok, but why shouldn't use  `GROUP BY`?  `ORDER BY` nearly opposite to `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Prochu1991 I never say not to use `GROUP BY`.  I said to use it properly.  Have you read the link that @RaymondNijland posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery for `sickAgg` no longer require this [`SUM((datediff(sickness.end_date, sickness.begin_date) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(sickness.end_date)) - time_to_sec(time(sickness.begin_date)))) AS vtime`] calculation since your `sickness` table already have `SICKNESS_TIME` column. The condition that you have to define is your `sickAgg` need to refer `END_DATE` column in you `order_status` table so that it will return only values before the `END_DATE`. Try this query below:

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
workers.lname, 
order_statusAgg.number_order,
workers.id_worker,
order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'TOTAL TIME', 
IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(sickAgg.vtime)),'00:00:00') AS 'SICK TIME'
FROM workers 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sickness.id_worker, TIME_TO_SEC(sickness_time) AS vtime FROM sickness 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id_worker,MIN(begin_date) AS 'MIN_BEGIN_DATE',MAX(end_date) AS 'MAX_END_DATE' 
FROM order_status GROUP BY id_worker) ordstat ON 
sickness.id_worker=ordstat.id_worker 
WHERE sickness.END_DATE <= MAX_END_DATE) sickAgg
       ON sickAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, 
SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.end_date) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime 
FROM order_status INNER JOIN orders 
       ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker) order_statusAgg
       ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 
WHERE order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker;
```

I have reconstruct the sub-query for your `sickAgg` entirely. Look at this part:

```
SELECT sickness.id_worker, TIME_TO_SEC(sickness_time) AS vtime FROM sickness 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id_worker,MIN(begin_date) AS 'MIN_BEGIN_DATE',MAX(end_date) AS 'MAX_END_DATE' 
FROM order_status GROUP BY id_worker) ordstat ON sickness.id_worker=ordstat.id_worker 
WHERE sickness.END_DATE <= MAX_END_DATE
```

Now, there are a lot of ways to do this and I am sure that in newer MySQL, there are better ways. But I think you understand what you write initially and it's better to work with what you understand first, rather than getting an entirely new query.

Comment: I've only changed in part which you edited. Instead  `TIME_TO_SEC(sickness_time)` i updated to: `SUM((datediff(sickness.END_DATE, sickness.BEGIN_DATE) + 1) * (time_to_sec(time(sickness.END_DATE)) - time_to_sec(time(sickness.BEGIN_DATE)))). Because SICKNESS_TIME is created from that query which i shew from update. But it does work perfectly. Thank you for much help! :)